# Chrome Websites track when location is disabled

Tags: chrome-for-android, geolocation, gps-tracking

I'd like a solution to prevent websites from tracking my geo location even with the android location service turned off. Certain sites such as craigslist, google and bing will turn up my geo location with cookies deleted and "Do not track" enabled.

Does anyone else have this problem or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use VPN. There is many free ones avilable such as Opera VPN, Hola, psiphon etc.